# Matrix and vector dimensions in w2v

Tags: word2vec, word-embedding

I need an explanation of the dimensions of matrices and vectors in word2vec (CBOW algorithm). What they exactly are, why do we need them and what I should know about that?

[image: Photo of CBOW model]

Answer (score -1):

The matrices represent the weights on the connections between the layers of the neural network. For example, the W'<sub>NxV</sub> matrix has N rows, one for each of the N components of the hidden layer, and V columns, one for each of the V components of the output layer. It's a matrix such that each element w'<sub>ij</sub> represents the weight for the connection between the ith neuron in the hidden layer, and the jth neuron in the output layer.